# SQL Server to select conditional on what time of year it currently is

Tags: sql, sql-server

I could use assistance in figuring out how to write my SQL query to pull records conditionally based on the current month. I have a table of officer listings that only list the year in the start and end date.

So, say someone is listed as President from 2015-2016, and someone else is listed as Treasurer from 2017-2018. Each year in May, the new term of officers is listed. So, I can't just base the query based on current year.

So, if the date was April 15, 2016, this would display: John Smith, President (2015-2016)

If the date was May 1, 2016, this would display: Sally Sue, President (2016-2017)

```
SELECT Name, Position, StartTerm, EndTerm 
FROM myTable 
WHERE (if before may, show last year's terms, if after may show next year's terms)
```

Comment: Subtract 4 months from the current date before using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, Position, StartTerm, EndTerm 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE YearOfTerms = Year(DateAdd(mm, -4, GetDate()))
```

Comment: perfect! thank you! i would've never thought of that.